# Resolve multiple constant drivers for net Error

Tags: vhdl, fpga, drivers

I do have following VHDL code example:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all; 

LIBRARY work;

ENTITY Test IS 
    PORT
    (   Nios_Reset_n :  IN  STD_LOGIC;
        UserLed :  OUT  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 DOWNTO 0)
    );
END Test;

ARCHITECTURE bdf_type OF Test IS 


COMPONENT misc
    PORT( reset_reset_n : IN STD_LOGIC;
         userleds_external_connection_export : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 DOWNTO 0)
    );
END COMPONENT;


BEGIN 

b2v_M1 : misc
PORT MAP(    reset_reset_n => Nios_Reset_n,
         userleds_external_connection_export => UserLed);

UserLed(0) <= '0';

END bdf_type;
```

After compiling I get following error message: **Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "UserLed[0]" at Test.vhd(28)**

What I figured out is, that the line **UserLed(0) <= '0';** gives the problem but I do not fully understand why because I have not used the signal UserLed elsewhere. It looks like an easy 'problem' here...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You HAVE used `UserLed` elsewhere : in a port map.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to introduce a local signal, so you can reassemble the LED wires:

```
architecture bdf_type of Test is 
  signal misc_leds : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 0);

  component misc
    port (
      reset_reset_n                       : IN  STD_LOGIC;
      userleds_external_connection_export : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 DOWNTO 0)
    );
  end component;
begin 
  b2v_M1 : misc
    port map (
      reset_reset_n =>                       Nios_Reset_n,
      userleds_external_connection_export => misc_leds
    );

  UserLed(0)          <= '0';
  UserLed(4 downto 1) <= misc_leds(4 downto 1);
end architecture;
```

Comment: ok but what is the reason of introduce a local signal "misc_leds"? You also changed the port map from **UserLed** to **misc_leds**. Why my example does not work?

Comment: why the line **UserLed(4 downto 1) <= misc_leds(4 downto 1);** if I only like to set **UserLed(0)**?

Comment: You are double assigning bit 0 of the led vector. So the tool complains that there are 2 drivers: misc and '0'. My solution stores all values in an intermediate signal and assigns bits 4..1 to the output. Bit 0 is assigned directly. So bit 0 from misc is 'floating'/unused.

Comment: one more thing: When I add the line `misc_leds(0)        <= '1';` I get the same error. Why?

Comment: @Norick all of the bits in misc_leds are already driven by their connection to userleds_external_connection in the portmap. Driving bit 0 of misc_leds to '0' in addition to the connection already in from the portmap gives a second driver to the signal. The compiler has a problem with this because it does not know what driver to choose since it cant choose to give bit 0 two different inputs.