# VHDL Internal Signal Declaration gives Driver Error

Tags: compiler-errors, driver, fpga

Here a simple code snipped with the problem that the compiler can not resolve multiple constant drivers for net "led_int[0]".

```
architecture bdf_type of Test is 
  signal led_int : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 0);

  component misc
    port (
      reset_reset_n                       : IN  STD_LOGIC;
      userleds_external_connection_export : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 DOWNTO 0)
    );
  end component;
begin 
  b2v_M1 : misc
    port map (
      reset_reset_n =>                       Nios_Reset_n,
      userleds_external_connection_export => led_int
    );

  led_int(0) <= '0';
  UserLed <= led_int;
end architecture;
```

Why do I get the same error message but here with **Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "led_int[0]" at Test.vhd(11)**?

How can I solve this simple problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resolve multiple constant drivers for net Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33122276/resolve-multiple-constant-drivers-for-net-error)

Answer (score 0):

You have two driver for the led_in(0) signal.

`led_int(0) <= '0';` is constantly pulling it low and `userleds_external_connection_export => led_int` pulls it either high or low depending on what is in the misc module.

You are not allowed to have two drivers for one signal in vhdl. If you wan't two drivers you need some logic in between them - such as an `or` gate , `and` gate, multiplexer or similiar.